# How do I determine which interface is referenced by an explicitly-implemented MethodInfo object?

Tags: .net, reflection, interface, methodinfo, explicit-interface

I have a `MethodInfo` object that represents an explicitly-implemented interface method, as follows.

```
MethodInfo GetMethod()
{
    return typeof(List<>).GetMethod(
        "System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator",
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
}
```

How do I query this `MethodInfo` object to obtain the interface type it implements, a `Type` object representing `System.Collections.IEnumerable`?  The [`InterfaceMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.interfacemapping.aspx) structure provides the inverse operation, getting the `MethodInfo` object of a type that implements a given interface, so that won't work.

Note that this is a contrived example as I can clearly parse the method name for this information.  I'd like to avoid doing this if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a direct way of doing this, but you can obviously use InterfaceMapping in reverse: iterate over all interfaces implemented by the method's declaring type, checking if the method is in the interface map for that interface:

```
foreach (Type itf in method.DeclaringType.GetInterfaces())
{
  if (method.DeclaringType.GetInterfaceMap(itf).TargetMethods.Any(m => m == method))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("match: " + itf.Name);
  }
}
```

Although this may seem a bit inefficient, most types implement few enough interfaces that it shouldn't be a big deal.  Appreciate it's not terribly elegant though!

Comment: This is likely the only way to accomplish the search, and has the added bonus of finding __all__ interface methods that are implemented by a single method.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about my first answer, at first I tried getting to the method through the `InterfaceMap` structure, and the methods in *that* structure actually **do** report the interface as the `DeclaringType`.  Then I tinkered with it and didn't realize it was subtly broken using the method you'd posted to get the `MethodInfo`.

The upside, though, is that this subtle difference led to the realization that the `MethodInfo` for the interface method, and the `MethodInfo` for the implementing method, are not actually the same method.  And upon further thought, I am actually pretty sure that what you want to do is impossible to do reliably.

Explicit interface implementations in C# are a bit of syntactic sugar over the way it really works in the CLR.  In other languages, a single concrete method can implement multiple interface methods the same way a concrete class can implement multiple interface types.  For example, in VB.NET, it's perfectly legal to do this:

```
Public Overrides Function Baz() As String Implements IFoo.Foo, IBar.Bar
```

Here you have one method that's explicitly implementing two interface methods.  If it were possible to get the original interface class - or even the original interface method - which one would you get?  How do you resolve the ambiguity?

I'm not an expert on the CLR internals, but I believe that interface maps are one-way.  When you implement an interface or method, implicitly or explicitly, the compiler creates a map *from* the interface *to* the implementation, and that's all it ever needs to handle method calls against the interface.

Think of the C#-generated method names as being almost coincidental.  Even though the method name is `System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator`, that really is just a name, and there is not actually any information about `System.Collections.IEnumerable` encoded in the method itself.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I've also noted that when a method maps explicitly to an interface method, it need only match in signature, and not by name.

Answer (score 0):

Try `MethodInfo.DeclaringType`.

Comment: This doesn't work for explicitly implemented interface methods.  It will return the type that implements the interface method, not the interface type.